# Custom component with combobox-like behaviour

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I am trying to create a custom component in flex that consists of a Button, and a TileList directly below that button. On button click event the TileList should open/close.
The component works fine, but when I add it to my main flex app, inside a VBox, it simply opens and closes within the VBox. Because the height of the VBox is much smaller than the custom component's TileList, it causes scrollbars. 
My issue with it is that it should behave like a ComboBox/Pull-down menu and go over the VBox, instead of going inside it.
Can someone please tell how to overlay the custom component, so it behaves like a ComboBox/Pull-down?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at using the PopUpManager. That will allow you to place the TileList so that it floats above other components when it's placed on the stage. You'll still need to figure out where to position it on the stage, but you can use the localToGlobal() and globalToLocal() methods to help you position the popup TileList.

Comment: Can you please point me to some example links, resources, etc for using the PopUpManager in the way explained above?

Comment: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/20/creating-custom-pop-up-windows-with-the-popupmanager-class-redux/

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html